# I want to put an i7-7700 into a Lenovo ideacentre 710-25ISH, what motherboard would I need for this?

Tags: motherboard, intel

I tried to put an i7-7700 into a Lenovo ideacentre 710-25ISH. It would not run. I cannot find a BIOS update to make the motherboard in this thing accept it. I was going to try and return the processor and get an i7-6700, which should work on this board. Alternatively though, I was thinking I could just buy a new motherboard that will accept this processor I already have.

Right now I have an Nvidia GTX 1050ti graphics card. I have 8GBx2 of RAM DDR4 (I also have 4GBx2 of RAM that came with the machine, but it refused to boot if I had all four inserted for some reason). I also have an SSD that did *not* come with the machine. I am unsure what its cable is, though its some form of SATA. The processor needs an LGA 1151 port. Not any one will do apparently though.

I'm on a budget, so I would prefer to not sink much more money into this if possible. I'm mainly making this post as a price-check honestly. What is the cheapest motherboard I could get that I could plug these components into and have them be accepted? Also,I mentioned the computer because I would prefer that the board fit inside the case I already have. A technician told me that it may be non-standard.

---

**Edit**: If it matters what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to turn my computer into a retrogaming machine. In particular, I'd like to run better graphics mods for Skyrim Legendary Edition. Being on linux, I can't run enbs sadly, but I would at least like to be able to run sweetfx without making my game struggle. Upgrading my ram did make a mild difference in that, though I was thinking a new processor would do the most good. Besides, I like to run a lot of script-heavy mods, and a better processor would surely help with that.

As for money, this processor cost me $180, and I was highly hesitant about that to give you an idea. I only bought the RAM too because those are actually cheap. And yes, I did try to do research before making my purchase, but it wasn't enough obviously. I didn't know the generation of processor mattered, I also found nothing telling me about the BIOS. Yeah, this has gone well so far. Honestly I'm mainly just trying to get something out of this at this point.

Comment: Hi! I know we spoke earlier; generally speaking, it's easier for us to help if we understand *what you're trying to solve*, rather than just *how you're trying to solve it.* Can you provide some more info about what you're trying to run on your computer, where it's currently struggling, and what your budget is?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and close this pending more information on your use case/what you're trying to do with your computer; please go ahead and add that information, and I'll reopen it after that.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a bit of an avalanche issue I suppose.
From what [I've](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Lenovo_Desktops/ideacentre_710/ideacentre_710_Spec.PDF) [read](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Desktops/Lenovo-MT90FL-BU-Y710-Cube-15ISH-with-I7-7700K/m-p/4384581) the motherboard will support an i7-6770 at most because Lenovo chose not to include support for newer CPUs in their BIOS updates.

The [motherboard](https://www.ebay.com/itm/263836746853) (please cross-check the image with yours) also doesn't seem to have a standard ATX 20/24-pin power supply connector.
That means that if you were to change your motherboard to something compatible with the i7-7700 - something like an [H110M-S03](https://www.ebay.de/itm/204538385046) which can be had for around 40$/€ - you'll also need a new power supply.
However, you'll likely need a new PSU anyway for when you may want to upgrade to a more powerful GPU.

Another option would be a newer Lenovo-specific mainboard for the 7700. The "[720-18IKL](https://de.scribd.com/document/486387983/ideacentre-720-18IKL-single-model-202006191100)" seems to be Lenovos update of the Ideacentre for the newer CPUs.
Those apparently use a motherboard called "[IB250MH](https://computerstoreberlin.de/Lenovo-IB250MH-Intel-B250-Mainboard-Sockel-1151-308373_1)".
It appears to have the same PSU connectors as your old mainboard, however it seems to be wider since it integrates the front panel USBs into the mainboard. I have no idea whether that might fit your older case though.

Regarding your RAM issue, have you made sure to balance the RAM amount over the slots?
Usually you would want it to have both a 4GB and a 8GB stick in each channel, check the manufacturers manual to verify which slots to use first as sometimes it can vary.
So from closest to the CPU to furthest it is usually (or vice versa): 8GB 8GB 4GB 4GB

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off returning the Intel I7-7700 and seeing if you could trade it in for a 6700 which would work without a doubt, the comparison of a 7700 vs 6700 is pretty negligible the only benefits of the 7700 would be is that it supports HEVC (10bit) and VP9 Encoding. The specs are virtually the same with the i7 having a slightly higher clock speed. If you can return it and get a 6700 you saved yourself the extra money and the frustration, skyrim is an older game and at it's core isn't cpu intensive but depending on what type of mods you are using it can use more of the CPU than usual but for a 10 year old game that 6700 would be perfect for the project you have in mind.

As for the ram the 7700 supports 64gb 2133mhz and the 6700 supports 32gb 2133mhz and both of the only support 2 slots in dual channel so that would be the reasoning why it wont boot when all the DIMM slots are populated, most the time you would install memory in the channels farthest from cpu so for instance slots 2 and 4 should be used but some manufacturers say to do 1 and 3 you would have to look at the manual for specs on that, sometimes the slots on the motherboard will have a star next to the ones that note which need to be used first and sometimes will be color coded.

You will save time and money just getting the 6700 instead of completely re-configuring your whole setup.

Extra note regarding the RAM configuration, in most use cases it's "okay" to use different ram sizes and/or timings but in general it's not good practice even though it will "work" it can cause minor issues. Most components these days will set the DIMMS equal to the smallest DIMM size so for instance installing 1x8gb stick and 1x4gb it would only allow the 8gb stick to run as 4gb and it will set the timings to the same as the 4gb stick as well. Which is just wasted memory so I would recommend sticking with the same brand/timings/size.